# Django debug toolbar installation (Django 1.9)

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar, django-1.9

I'm using python 3.5.1 with django 1.9.4 in virtualenv (Windows). I'm trying to add the django-debug-toolbar but I get an error when starting the server.

I added 'django_debug' in my installed_apps, and also 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware' in my middleware_classes.

Pip freeze log:

```
Django==1.9.4
django-debug-toolbar==1.4
sqlparse==0.1.19
```

Runserver:

**ImportError: No module named 'django_debug'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install django-debug-toolbar by doing:

```
 pip3 install django-debug-toolbar (pip3 since you're using python3),
```

And next in your INSTALLED_APPS add:

```
'debug_toolbar'
```

and not django_debug, and also remove the middleware you added(not sure of it, as I never added it).

Comment: Hi, thank you for spotting that 'debug_toolbar' error. I don't know why I typed it like that. That was the clear deal breaker :)

Thank you for your reply, it's now working!

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `debug_toolbar` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and **not** `django_debug`.

Also, you can remove the class that you added in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`. As given in the docs:

> If `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` doesn’t contain the middleware, the Debug Toolbar automatically adds it the beginning of the list.

You can have a look at the [docs](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.4/installation.html#quick-setup).